# estimate probability that sensitivity/specificity greater than threshold value

Tags: bayesian, diagnostic, sensitivity-specificity

Is there a Bayesian method to estimate the probability that the sensitivity of a diagnostic test is greater than some value, say 0.70? Rather than estimate sensitivity and a confidence interval (e.g., 0.80 [0.7-0.9]), I want to say that there's a 82% probability that the test's sensitivity is greater than 0.70.

Comment: Suppose [0.7-0.9] is 82% CI. Then you can say that sensitivity is between 0.7 and 0.9 with 82% probability. ==> you can also say that there's a 82% probability that the test's sensitivity is greater than 0.70.

Comment: Thanks, @a_statistician. I don't see how having an 82% CI that ranges from 0.7-0.9 equals an 82% probability that the value is greater than the lower bound of the CI.